# find and replace property value in json object using javascript/underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have one list as follows

```
var data = [{id:1, name:'user1', img:'img1.jpg' },{id:2, 'user2', img:'img2.jpg' }]
```

Now I have to replace img property with new value (e.g. 'New_Image_2.jpg') for id=2 using underscore.js or in javascript using less effort. right now I have created one small function as follows.

```
var imgpath = 'New_Image_2.jpg';
var tmpdata = _.findWhere(data,{id:2});
if (tmpdata) {
    tmpdata.img = imgpath;
}
```

Now, in above method, my problem is, How to marge new value with original data?

Comment: Please execute your program and check. Its already working fine.

Comment: `_.findWhere(data,{id:2});` returns the actual object and you are mutating the object. So, the changes are actually made in the object which has `img2.jpg`

Comment: Here's a Fiddle illustrating what @thefourtheye says http://jsfiddle.net/dMCx3/ Note that `data` in your question is invalid (missing `name:` in front of 'user2')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code should already work because `_.findWhere` returns the first object corresponding to your constraint or `undefined` if it does not exist, it means that modifying `tmpdata.img` actually modifies the value you want to modify.